# Mousemove animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Hello I am trying to achive this effect http://mario.ign.com/modern-era/super-mario-3D-world no mousemove I would like to do it with some kind of ease effect to make it smooth but actually dont know how to achive de desaceleration effect, so far what I've done is this  http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/8RB24/1/:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var contWidth = $container.width();
var $point = $('.point');
var delay = 100;

$container.mousemove(function(e){
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(e.offsetX);
        $point.each(function(){
            if( e.offsetX > (contWidth - $point.width())){
                return;
            }
            var xp = $(this).position().left;
            xp += parseFloat((e.offsetX - xp)/ 20);
            $(this).css({
                left: xp
            });
        });
    }, delay);

});
```

But I think that the animation doesnt feel as smooth as mario site i would appreciate if you guys could help me ginding resources or guiding me to achieve this effect. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use a tweening library like TweenLite or TweenJS, makes it super easy.

Comment: Yeah but is for learning purposes, I would like in some way to achive it my self before using any library. Like I feel loading a full library for just that effect its not good

Comment: practically everyone uses Robert Penner's algorithms:  http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/

Comment: https://github.com/stephband/jparallax/blob/master/js/jquery.parallax_1.0.js This is the plugin used by that mario website. You could try and learn from its code. It is not as complicated as it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choppiness is because it's running solely on the mousemove event.  If you break it out into an interval (say 30 frames per second), it will be much smoother. This way it continues to ease even after the mouse stops.

```
var $container = $('#container');
var contWidth = $container.width();
var $point = $('.point');
var delay = 100;
var decay = .1;

var intervalId;
var mouseX, mouseY;

//this function is called 30 times per second.
function ticker(){
     $point.each(function(){
         if( mouseX > (contWidth - $point.width())){
             mouseX = (contWidth - $point.width()); //instead of returning, just set the value to the max
         }
         var xp = $(this).position().left;
         xp += parseFloat((mouseX - xp) * decay); //using a decay variable for easier tweaking
         $(this).css({
            left: xp
         });
     });
}

//this interval calls the ticker function every 33 milliseconds
intervalId = setInterval(ticker, 33); //33 millisecond is about 30 fps  (16 would be roughly 60fps)

$container.mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.offsetX; //store the current mouse position so we can reference it during the interval
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
});
```

Comment: This is workign pretty well, feels smooth and all but dont understand very well what is the differencie betwen the setTiemout i was using and your setInterval, pretty much this portsion of the code.

  `if(!intervalId){ 
     intervalId = setInterval(function(){...
    }, 33); //30 fps`

Comment: Set interval runs over and over again,  setTimeout runs only once.  So before your setTimeout function was called once (per mouse move).  With setInterval it's independent of the mouse move event and just runs every 33 milliseconds.

Comment: Cool this worked for me so good. One last question. if I would like the blue point to move contrary to mouse direction how howld i do thath? i trid doing `$(this).css({left: xp* -1});` but it behaves really weird

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i could use that script to study for sure, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this. not sure it this is what you want but it sure does "a" trick.

```
$container.mousemove(function(e){

    var xp = e.clientX-offset;
    blue.css({
        left: xp+'px'
     });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d65yan/8RB24/2/

look at the .blue{} css
some vendro prefix are needed if you want to support older versions of moz and chrome, forget about ie up to version 9 though

Comment: This one works pretty good I think, just that in short mouse movements feels like jumping but could be a good solution

Comment: thats because of the start delay and the transition function, the smaller the delay the better it will respond to small changes, but then you'll loose the delay.. also if you change the function to linear it would respond better.Right now am using ease, but you can set others even custom ones, check out css transitions for more details

Comment: If browser compatibility isn't an issue (and you don't require any additional logic in how it moves), this is a more efficient and graceful way of doing it than an interval