# CSS3 radial gradient rendering in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I was animating radial gradients with jQuery when I suddenly noticed something strange (check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6wbt34s/)). When the mouse pointer is moved over the left side of the element the position animation is smooth, but when far to the right it isn't smooth at all (notice the jumps in position if you move your mouse slowly enough).

[image: Screen recording of the phenomenon]

This feels like some kind of rounding error, but I'm not sure as to why it happens. Any ideas? I have only tested it on Google Chrome for the time being and it only happens in the horizontal direction.

**CSS**

```
html { background: #fff; }
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body { background: #000; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;

    $(this).css('background', '-webkit-radial-gradient(' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px, transparent 10%, #000 5%)');
});
```

Can you replicate this or does it only happen to me?

**EDIT:** Works fine in Safari.

Comment: I can't replicate it. What version are you using? When you move your mouse far to the right, does your mouse go over the scroll bars (because then the `mousemove` event won't fire)?

Comment: I think I'm using the latest non-beta release (can't check atm) and I'm not hovering the scroll bar. The effect is clearer the bigger the element is and the further to the right the mouse is moved.

Comment: Happens for me in Chrome on Windows 8

Comment: Using version 38.0.2125.104 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate it: like it's is said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683990/mousemove-animation), it's not smooth because it's relying on the mousemove event only. Try to use a ticker, that's relying on time intervals. I modified your fiddle to use the ticker found in the already linked thread, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/rh4Ljro4/

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
var container = $('body');
var contWidth = container.width();

var intervalId;
var mouseX, mouseY;

//this function is called 60 times per second.
function ticker(){
     $(container).css('background', '-webkit-radial-gradient(' + mouseX + 'px ' + mouseY + 'px, transparent 10%, #000 5%)');
}

//this interval calls the ticker function every 16 milliseconds
intervalId = setInterval(ticker, 16); //33 millisecond is about 30 fps while 16 would be roughly 60fps

container.mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.offsetX; //store the current mouse position so we can reference it during the interval
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
});
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem as the original

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say it solved it for me. It has some problems only  near the border, but that's because the mouse probably goes over the scrollbar. That is solved reducing the width end height of the container, at least for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ufs8yL0b/

Comment: It's the same for me as well.